# Closing a form on another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

A have a form that will show another form when you click logout. I want to close or hide both forms when you click yes and it will go to my login form. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: OK, but what have you tried? I'd suggest to read this: [ask]

Comment: Please show some code, especially the parts where you show that second form.

Comment: winforms? wpf? something else?

Comment: Confirmation frm = new Confirmation(UserID, Username);
frm.Show();

well that's the code..

Comment: Pass the parent form as a parameter to the child form, you can close both forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Form's `Owner` property to set child form's owner:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Owner = this;
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Then in your secondary form you close it:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Owner != null)
            this.Owner.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me.

Comment: You can also use Form's `Owner` property to do the job, which would be a better solution. Take a look at updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a WinForm solution:

```
private void bLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult result= MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to logout?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
   if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
    this.Hide();
    new frmLogin().Show(); 
   }
}
```